# Conflict in CLR parsing

Tags: parsing, lalr, parse-tree, compiler-construction

This is the grammar:

```
S' -> S
S-> aBc|bCc|aCd|bBd
B ->e
C ->e
```

I parsed in CLR then reduce/reduce conflict arose. What to do next? I have attached my solved problem below.

[image: Parse Table]

[image: This is process]

Answer (score 3):

> Anybody please tell me what to do next

Err... fix the conflict?

It's very clear even just from the last two productions, when the parser meets either c or d after e:

```
B -> e . {c, d}
C -> e . {c, d}
```

single lookahead is not enough to determine whether above condition should reduce to B or C.

Parser generators usually have a solution by taking the one that appears first in the grammar, but this is not always a good case. In above grammar, if this solution is taken, the parser won't be able to parse bec and aed due to e always reduces to B.

I suggest changing the grammar such that no conflict occurs. You know the whole grammar can only produce aec, bec, aed and bed. See what's better in the sequences to be made separate production that will reduce uniquely.

Comment: It have reduce/reduce conflict.So don't we have solution for this? Rather than changing the grammar.

Comment: Well... some parser generators allow you to specify precedence of certain tokens, but since you're learning language theory and automaton, I don't think you're allowed to take implementation-specific concept into the task. Here's a link to related bison case article: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Reduce_002fReduce.html